# Docker log network traffic during build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In docker, how do I log all network traffic happening during build.

I imagine I will modify my dockerfile to monitor and collect all network requests. For instance from `apt-get install` and installing node or rubygem packages

I am OK with modifying the Dockerfile to collect a log or output it in another way.

Any suggestions as to how I could do that?

Answer (score 1):

All network traffic = traffic on all interfaces (`loopback` included) and all protocols (not only `http/https`, where you can use logging via proxy). Start `tcpdump` in the background at the beggining of each `RUN` command for all interfaces (`eth0, lo`). Example, which will print all packets to `stdout`:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add tcpdump

# start tcpdumps in the background for each RUN
RUN sh -c 'tcpdump -nnXSs 0 -i eth0 &' \
    && sh -c 'tcpdump -nnXSs 0 -i lo &' \
    && ping -c 5 google.com

RUN sh -c 'tcpdump -nnXSs 0 -i eth0 &' \
    && sh -c 'tcpdump -nnXSs 0 -i lo &' \
    && apk add curl
```

Build output:

```
...
Step 3/4 : RUN sh -c 'tcpdump -nnXSs 0 -i eth0 &'     && sh -c 'tcpdump -nnXSs 0 -i lo &'     && ping -c 5 google.com
 ---> Running in 63249712af4a
PING google.com (216.58.204.78): 56 data bytes
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.204.78: seq=0 ttl=127 time=17.529 ms
13:01:09.987047 IP 8.8.4.4.53 > 172.17.0.2.43264: 41194 1/0/0 A 216.58.204.46 (44)
        0x0000:  4500 0048 7096 0000 7f11 12f0 0808 0404  E..Hp...........
        0x0010:  ac11 0002 0035 a900 0034 0472 a0ea 8180  .....5...4.r....
        0x0020:  0001 0001 0000 0000 0667 6f6f 676c 6503  .........google.
        0x0030:  636f 6d00 0001 0001 c00c 0001 0001 0000  com.............
        0x0040:  001e 0004 d83a cc2e 
...
```

Of course, you can send these logs to Elasticsearch/Splunk/..., but you will need to install more toolings. And probably it will be good idea to exclude this traffic from `tcpdump`.